# Selling/Generating Revenue from Unused Domain Names

Tags: domains, advertising

I have a domain name which has a relevantly top searched keyword in it. I have not used this for over a year but I plan on doing so soon. Where is the best place to put it up for auction or see if anyone would like to buy it? (I am in the UK) and also Is there a way I can generate revenue from this unused domain name because at the moment I'm just paying for the domain name costs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are services that you park your domain on their server and you split the revenue with them earned from the ads they place on it. I never used these kinds of services so I can't give a recommendation as to a good one but I'm sure you cn find a bunch with a search or two.

To sell a domain see these sites ([from this previous answer](http://sedo.com)):

- Snapnames.com
- Sedo.com
- Godaddy.com Auctions
- Auctionpus.com
- Ebay.com
- Latonas.com
- Afternic.com
- Domainmonkey.com
- Bido.com
- Domaintools.com
- Greatdomains.com (Part Of Sedo)
- Namejet.com
- Snapnames.com
- Winyourdomain.com

You can also try to sell it via the specialized forums (incomplete list):

- dnforum.com
- namepros.com
- domainforums.com

Comment: ♦ If you put a domain name on one of these sites as an auction does that mean you will have to then sell it if a bid gets placed? I have no idea how it works. thanks

Comment: Not sure. I guess it depends on how it's set up. I would think there would be a reserve feature where if the price isn't high enough you can walk away. I know ebay does that. I'm sure others do, too.